# Overloading == and !== when object is a pointer

Tags: pointers, visual-c++, operators

I am new to writing operators (in this case `==` and `!=`). I have done a bit of research and so far came up with:

```
bool operator==(const SPECIAL_EVENT_S &rsEvent)
{
    bool bSame = false;

    if (rsEvent.datEvent == m_datSpecialEvent &&
        rsEvent.strEvent == m_strNotes &&
        rsEvent.strLocation == m_strLocation &&
        rsEvent.datEventStartTime == m_datEventStartTime &&
        rsEvent.datEventFinishTime == m_datEventFinishTime &&
        gsl::narrow<bool>(rsEvent.bEventAllDay) == m_bEventAllDay &&
        gsl::narrow<bool>(rsEvent.bSetReminder) == m_bSetReminder &&
        rsEvent.iReminderUnitType == m_iReminderUnitType &&
        rsEvent.iReminderInterval == m_iReminderInterval &&
        rsEvent.iImageWidthPercent == m_wImageWidthPercent &&
        rsEvent.strImagePath == m_strImagePath &&
        rsEvent.strTextBeforeImage == m_strTextBeforeImage &&
        rsEvent.strTextAfterImage == m_strTextAfterImage &&
        rsEvent.eType == m_eVideoconfType &&
        rsEvent.sBSSTI == m_sBSSTI)
    {
        // The fundamental information is unchanged
        bSame = true;
    }

    // Now compare the MWB Event Type
    if (bSame)
    {
        switch (rsEvent.eMWBEventType)
        {
        case EventTypeMWB::MWBBethelSpeakerServiceTalk:
            return m_bSpecialEventBethelServiceTalk;
        case EventTypeMWB::MWBVideoconferenceAssembly:
            return m_bSpecialEventVideoconf && m_eVideoconfType == VideoConferenceEventType::Live;
        case EventTypeMWB::MWBVideoconferenceConvention:
            return m_bSpecialEventVideoconf && m_eVideoconfType == VideoConferenceEventType::Recorded;
        case EventTypeMWB::MWBSpecialEvent:
            return m_bSpecialEvent;
        case EventTypeMWB::MWBMemorial:
            return m_bEventMemorial;
        case EventTypeMWB::MWBCircuitOverseerMeeting:
            return m_bCircuitVisit || m_bCircuitVisitGroup;
        case EventTypeMWB::MWBMeeting:
            return !m_bNoMeeting;
        default:
            bSame = false;
        }
    }

    return bSame;
}
bool operator!=(const SPECIAL_EVENT_S& rsEvent)
{
    return !(rsEvent == *this);
}
```

What surprised me what when I then tried to use these operators:

```
if (pEntry != sEvent)
{
    AfxMessageBox(_T("The special event information has changed"));
}
```

It does not like `pEntry` being a pointer. In the end I did this:

```
if (*pEntry != sEvent)
{
    AfxMessageBox(_T("The special event information has changed"));
}
```

1. Why was this an issue in the first place? I ask that because if this was a standard function it would not matter if the object was a pointer or not.
2. What is the correct way to cater for this scenario?

For example:

- `object->Function(value)`
- `object.Function(value)`

`Function` can be used both by the object when it is / is not a pointer. So why not with an `operator`?

Comment: What do you mean by "_if this was a standard function it would not matter if the object was a pointer or not_"? Could you please be more specific and give an example of such "standard function" where this doesn't matter?

Comment: @heapunderrun I mean: `object->Function(value)` or `object.Function(value)`. `Function` can be used both by the object when it is / is not a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *`Function` can be used both by the object when it is / is not a pointer.*

Actually, no it can't. In a statement/expression like `object->Function(value)` the `->` (member access) and `()` (function call) operators have the [same precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) and **left-to-right associativity**. So, the `->` is applied first and that automatically dereferences the pointer. So, the effect is the same as `(*object).Function(value)` – and `Function` is *still* being called on an *object*, rather than on a pointer.

> *So why not with an `operator`?*

The syntax for calling an `operator` function is (or *can* be) rather different: *because* it is defined as an operator, you can call it using the operator token (between the two operands) rather than by using an explicit function call. But then, you *have* to pass objects, as that's what the operands are defined to be.

However, should you really want to, you *can* still call an operator override using explicit function-call syntax; and, in that case, you can use the `->` on a pointer; like this (where `operator==` is effectively the 'name' of the function):

```cpp
if (!pEntry->operator==(sEvent))
{
    AfxMessageBox(_T("The special event information has changed"));
}
```

However, this seems like a lot of hard work and your `*pEntry != sEvent` is actually the 'correct' way to use the override.

---

PS: As bonus, if you're using a compiler that supports the C++20 (or later) Standard, you can add a ["defaulted" `operator==`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons) to your structures/classes, which would save you explicitly comparing each individual data member:

```cpp
struct foo {
    int a;
    double b;
    bool operator==(const foo&) const = default; // Compares "a" and "b"
};

struct bar {
    foo f;
    int c;
    int d;
    bool operator==(const bar&) const = default; // Compares "c", "d" and "f"
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations and background information.I am using the C++20 standard to compile this project. You mention using a *defaulted operator==* but I am not so sure that is OK in this scenario? If you check my `==` logic they don't all have a like for like counterpart. The section at the bottom uses a switch. This is because we are not actually comparing to objects of the same type and is the reason why I needed the custom `==` logic. Am I missing something here?

Comment: OK - the defaulted operators will compare all data members (and any non-primitive member must, itself, have a `==` defined). Sorry if I didn't fully read your custom comparators.

Comment: Also, I just noticed that you *don't* have automatic deduction of `!=` from `==`.  But again, in C++20 you can use that feature so, if you have a `==`, you also have (implicitly) a `!=` (which generally does what you would expect it to do).

Comment: Are you saying that if I add a `==` in both places that I do not need to specifically add a `!=` operator?

Comment: Yes. Having a `==` operator allows for inequality testing since C++20. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons)